# Insert query using joins in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named question table and answer table.

I have to write insert query for answer table based on question id as column which is primary key in answer table. So how can i write query for it?

Comment: Can you show us your so far code ?

Comment: In addition to previous poster, is this purely sql, or are you writing to db with using another language?

Comment: Just a normal insert query done this. But you have to make sure that you have already applied primary & foreign key constraints.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use where clause.. If you have to insert on basis of question_id you can just use

`INSERT INTO anser_table (answer) VALUES ('Your answer') WHERE question_id = 'id' ;`